# Why do child margins render outside of divs?

Tags: css

Could someone explain to me what are the possible benefits of the CSS behavior where a child elements top and bottom margins render outside the `block`-parents render bounds?

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvw1bop4/) for a super simple example. The pink `div` is affected by the `h1`'s margins.

I'm guessing it has something to do with collapsing margins, but it's really not clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

styles by straight:

1. Body.
2. Pure html.
3. Css..

is pure html. he will affect all divs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the OP asked.